# Using html templates in angular's ng-switch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-switch

Im making an 'interactive menu' that moves along with user clicks.
Im wondering if there is a way to include html templates in ng-switch,
since all the logic is different in each 'switch' - it will result in huge html files.

```
<div class="content" ng-switch on="selection">
 <div ng-switch-when="1" >
   <h1>1</h1>
 </div>
 <div ng-switch-when="2">
   <h1>2</h1>       
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `ngInclude`:

```
<div class="content" ng-switch on="selection">
    <div ng-switch-when="1" >
        <ng-include src="'template1.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
        <ng-include src="'template2.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Dont forget to use single quotes wrapped inside the double quotes if you are hard-coding the path.

Comment: +1 just for pointing out the crucial point that one has to use single quotes as well, along with double quotes. If not used, the templates wont show up.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to do it with `ng-include` directive :

```
<div class="content" ng-switch on="selection">
    <ng-switch-when="1" ng-include="//TEMPLATE PATH">
    <ng-switch-when="2" ng-include="//TEMPLATE 2 PATH">
</div>
```

Comment: This is the better answer as it uses less markup (ng-include and switch on the same element)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake looks like there are problems: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4731

Comment: As of Angular 1.2, you can't use ng-include inside ng-switch. If you want less markup than @CodeHater's answer, use <div ng-if="selection===1" ng-include="'html/template1.html'"></div>

Comment: Can this be done by tweaking the Directive itself so that templateUrl only loads on switch

Comment: I get an error using this method `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngSwitchWhen, ngInclude] asking for transclusion on: <div ng-switch-when="1" ng-include="'temp1.html'">`

Answer (score 1):

```
   **I used ng-Include this way.**

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- right col -->
      <section class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive ui-tabbed" id="myTab">
          <li class="active">
            <a  data-ng-click=' main.active.tab = "tab-1" '>Tab 1</a>
          </li>

    </ul>
    <!-- end responsive tabs -->

    <div class="tab-content ui-tabbed-contents responsive">
    <div data-ng-switch = " main.active.tab ">
      <div data-ng-switch-when='tab-1' >
        <ng-include src="'tab-one.html'" ></ng-include>
      </div>

    </div>

    </div>


    </div>
    <!-- end main tabs container -->
    </section>
```