# Angular: using ng-if to change my jade files

Tags: angularjs

Ok I am getting the **speciality** value from my angular controller and based on that value I want to change  my UI view with different files.
 Right now I am getting all the three files one after another in my view, seems the ng-if is not checking the condition, any help would be appreciated.

```
div(ng-if = 'speciality = "null"')
  include consultation-form
div(ng-if = 'speciality = "Ophthalmology"')
  include consultation
div(ng-if = 'speciality = "Cardiology"')
  include add-User-Dependents
```

Comment: I don't know this syntax, but u sure that a single "=" is enough?

Comment: Can you show us compiled version of this? (raw html)

Comment: May be you've trouble with quotes. try to use `"speciality='null'"` style

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20095119/2460773

Comment: Use "==", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: Yup it sems '==' is the solution, thanks